# How to display stdout of command in `less` with as few keystrokes as possible?

Tags: bash, terminal, zsh, less, fish

I often find myself piping a command's output into `less` because `less` is far superior for studying the output than the normal terminal.

While I can always append `| less` to every command, I was wondering if there is a more concise way of doing this requiring fewer keystrokes.

One option would be to alias `less` allowing me to type `|L` instead of `|less`.

Is there a smarter way? Like binding `| less` to a certain key combination?

I use `fish` but answers for `zsh` and `bash` are equally welcome, though more generic ones are preferred.

Comment: Similar: [Filter by default](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/536692)

Comment: I use `alias p=less` myself (mnemonic: p for "pager") -- p is close to the pipe on the keyboard.

Comment: @glennjackman, FWIW, on a UK PC keyboard, The `P` and `|` (Shift+`\ `) keys couldn't be further apart.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is a [custom key binding](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/interactive.html?custom-bindings#custom-bindings). Example:

```
bind \el "commandline --insert '| less'"
```

now pressing alt-L or option-L will insert `| less` at your cursor.

Comment: Sounds like this would also be a good use-case for [global abbreviations (#5003)](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/5003) when implemented.

Comment: Great answer! What do you need to add so that it's automatically executed - meaning I don't have to hit enter?

Comment: May be better to wrap the `<command>` in `begin <command>; end | less` (or `(<command>)|less` in `zsh`) and avoid that wrapping being added to the history.

Answer (score 7):

For this specific thing: Press alt+p. Fish binds that to add  `&| less` by default.

Comment: On my system, pressing `Alt+p` just outputs the character `π`.  I'm connecting to my system via iTerm2 on macOS. Using `Esc` in place of `Alt` seems to work though.

Comment: That's because your iTerm is configured to do special output. Escape works in place of alt because alt *is* escape. The normal thing for terminals to do is to send escape+key when you press alt+key. Pressing escape in this manner only works up to a timeout, because fish has to determine if you meant escape on its own, and the only way to do it is to wait. Other programs have similar solutions.

Comment: @Kusalananda: You need to make `option` behave as `meta`:
1. Command + O to open the iTerm2 profiles
2. Click Edit Profiles
3. Choose left option key as +Esc or both left and right option key on the bottom right corner
4. Close the iTerm2 Profiles
Source: https://blog.m157q.tw/posts/2014/07/09/use-option-key-as-meta-in-iterm2-and-terminal-on-mac/

Comment: Woah :D Fish *is* amazing. Always got another goody somewhere by default.

Comment: Also note that Fish will use the PAGER variable, if set, so you can use `bat`  ([bat](https://github.com/sharkdp/bat)) if you'd like.